# Conditionally run program using Rosetta 2 on M1 Mac

Tags: xcode, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

Is it possible to start a program using the command line in a way that has it run by Rosetta 2, without having the application setting that forces the program to always be running under Rosetta 2.

e.g.

- click dock icon for Xcode → launches Xcode **NOT** through Rosetta 2
- run `open -a xcode --rosetta2` → launches Xcode through Rosetta 2

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `arch` command to force a preferred slice loading order for universal binaries. In your particular case, you would first make sure to Get Info on Xcode and uncheck the "Open using Rosetta" checkbox in Finder. Then via command line you can force loading the x86_64 slice:

```
arch -x86_64 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

See `man arch` for more details.

Example:

```
echo "arch" > build.sh
arch -arm64 /bin/bash ./build.sh 
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash ./build.sh
```

Outputs:

```
arm64
i386
```